# docker arp сканирование.

Tags: java, docker, arp

Имеется микросервисное приложение. Один из сервисов производит arp сканирование окружающей локальной сети с помощью скрипта. 
Вопрос в то что упакованный в контейнер докера jar-ник, сканирует только внутреннюю сеть контейнера, а требуется чтобы он коннектился к внешней среде. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/

Comment: не совсем что нужно.

Comment: host mode я включаю но он сканирует все равно только то что внутри контейнера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Проблема оказалась в специфике работы mac os. При запуске на linux проблема исчезла